# Regex leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex expression that allows `a-z`, `A-Z`, any number, spaces, but it has to disallow whitespace at the END.

So far I have:

```
[a-zA-Z' ']+
```

I'm not sure how to allow any number and trim the whitespace at the end

Comment: You want to trim the whitespace at the end of the line or just not match a line that has whitespace at the end?

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty simple:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

I just special-cased the last character here. This required turning `+` into `*` for the remaining characters.

Comment: this one is better. try to avoid lookahead/lookbehind if it can be.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr may i know why?

Comment: @AvinashRaj depends on the engine. look ahead and behind are generally slow. it may be typically equivalent to having the main re matched, then try to match the look ahead or behind part based on that. so potentially, in the worst case, having an extra look ahead or behind would raise re to search O(n^2) characters instead of O(n).

Comment: just play with the first regex of mine and the Lucas regex on this site https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/5 . Check the debugger at the left side. Then you know which one take more number of steps.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it really seems to depend on engine. the engine of regex101 is obviously not optimized. in automaton's prospective, a mismatch should be known right after reaching the end of the string. https://www.debuggex.com/r/6cJ2Q0d7nB7-wmdT

Comment: @AvinashRaj want an optimized regex without lookarounds? Try this one: `^(?: *+[a-zA-Z0-9]++)*+$` :-) More seriously, lookarounds may optimize the matching on NFA engines. I went for the basic safest approach since the OP didn't specify which regex flavour he's using.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?!.*\s$)[a-zA-Z\d ]+
```

`(?!.*\s$)` asserts that there isn't a space character exists at the end.

**OR**

```
^[a-zA-Z\d ]+(?<!\s)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/4)

Answer (score 0):

how about this pattern using word boundary `\b`
 `\b[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\b`